# How to change the public directory of a next js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, monorepo

I have a monorepo with the following architecture:

```
apps/
  web/
    - next.config.js
    - pages/
public/
```

My next js application is in the `apps/web/` folder. How do I change the `next.config.js` file so that it knows to serve public assets from the public folder at the root of my monorepo and not in the `apps/web/` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving), you cannot

> Note: Be sure the directory is named public. The name cannot be
> changed and is the only directory used to serve static assets.
>
> Note: Only assets that are in the public directory at build time will
> be served by Next.js. Files added at runtime won't be available. We
> recommend using a third party service like AWS S3 for persistent file
> storage.